# Difference between twofold infinity and simple infinity in relation to quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, polarization

$\newcommand{\k}[1]{\left | #1 \right\rangle }$ In his "*[The Principles of Quantum Mechanics](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/scientists/dirac/chapter_1.html)*", Paul Dirac states:

> $$c_1\k A + c_2 \k B = \k R$$

Given two states corresponding to the ket vectors $\k A$ and $\k B $, the general state formed by superposing them corresponds to a ket vector  $\k R$ which is determined by two complex numbers, namely the coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$ of equation (1). If these two coefficients are multiplied by the same factor (itself a complex number), the ket vector $\k R$ will get multiplied by this factor and the corresponding state will be unaltered. Thus only the ratio of the two coefficients is effective in determining the state $R$.

*Hence this state is determined by one complex number, or by two real parameters. Thus from two given states, a **twofold infinity of states** may be obtained by superposition.*

> This result is confirmed by the examples discussed in $§§$ $2$ and $3$. In
>   the example of $§$ $2$ there are just two independent states of
>   polarization for a photon, which may be taken to be the states of
>   plane polarization parallel and perpendicular to some fixed direction,
>   and from the superposition of these two a twofold infinity of states
>   of polarization can be obtained, namely all the states of elliptic
>   polarization, the general one of which requires two parameters to
>   describe it. Again, in the example of $§$ $3$, from the superposition of
>   two given translational states for a photon a twofold infinity of
>   translational states may be obtained, the general one of which is
>   described by two parameters, which may be taken to be the ratio of the
>   amplitudes of the two wave functions that are added together and their
>   phase relationship.

*This confirmation shows the need for allowing complex coefficients in equation ($1$). If these coefficients were restricted to be real, then, since only their ratio is of importance for determining the direction of the resultant ket vector $\k R$ when  $\k A$ and $\k B$ are given, there would be only a **simple infinity of states** obtainable from the superposition.*

---

The above two paragraphs have been directly quoted from the aforementioned book.

The **QUESTION** is as mentioned in the title:

1. What is the basic difference between twofold infinity and simple infinity? I mean, in mathematics, there is only one infinity as much as I knew.
2. How is this difference interpreted in quantum mechanics? That is, does these things have a special *abstract* meaning here?
3. And how does it even relate to states of polarisation? Can you suggest a suitable link to study these suitable states of polarisation like elliptical polarisation, circular polarisation,.. etc? I don't know what these are.

**P.S.** I found an [answer](http://functionspace.com/topic/3515/opinion/6373) to this question on functionspace but I couldn't clear my doubts using it. It was high above my level. So please try to use basic concepts of QM and, simple language and terms which I, a beginner, can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is highly outdated language. What Dirac calls a 'twofold infinity of states' we would today call a two dimensional manifold. The distinct states $|R\rangle$ can be parametrized by two real parameters and form a two dimensional [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere).

If we restricted the coefficients $c_1, c_2$ to be real the condition that  $|R\rangle$ must have unit norm would require the allowed states to form a one-dimensional manifold parametrized by one real parameter. For instance the parameter is $\theta$ and
$$c_1 = \cos \theta,\quad c_2=\sin\theta$$

The connection with polarization is if we take $|A\rangle,|B\rangle$ to be two perpendicular linear polarized waves. Complex combinations of $|A\rangle,|B\rangle$ lead to elliptically polarized waves in general (see [Jones vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus)), and Dirac's audience would know that these require two real parameters to describe.